# What is the purpose of JOBS folder in `D:\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\`?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

I am exploring SQL 2022.

In my SQL server path, there is a folder called JOBS.

```
D:\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\JOBS
```

What is the purpose of this folder?

Comment: I see this on all instances on my machine - earliest I've got installed is 2016. It is empty for me so I don't know under what circumstances this would get used

Comment: I have a feeling that this is a leftover from very old days...

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of this question is the same as your [FullText folder question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/329645/150011), in regards to backups, then there's no need to do anything special regarding backups of SQL Agent Jobs. Regular database backups of the system databases will have you covered.

In particular, the data for SQL Agent Jobs are stored in the `msdb` database. So long as you backup that database routinely, you'll be ok. For further reading, please see [SQL Server Agent Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/sql-server-agent-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> All tables are in the dbo schema in the msdb database.

Comment: What is the purpose of JOBS folder?

Comment: @variable Honestly I don't know. I've never seen it actually in use.